# Python and reference passing. Limitation?

Tags: python, pass-by-reference

I would like to do something like the following:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.member = 10
        pass

def factory(foo):
    foo = Foo()

aTestFoo = None
factory(aTestFoo)

print aTestFoo.member
```

However it crashes with `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'member'`:
the object `aTestFoo` has not been modified inside the call of the function `factory`.

What is the pythonic way of performing that ? Is it a pattern to avoid ? If it is a current mistake, how is it called ?

In C++, in the function prototype, I would have added a reference to the pointer to be created in the factory... but maybe this is not the kind of things I should think about in Python.

In C#, there's the key word `ref` that allows to modify the reference itself, really close to the C++ way. I don't know in Java... and I do wonder in Python.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do here? Also, why do you need a factory function?

Comment: The code in question is relatively simple to answer about my concern. Of course a return in the factory function with a direct assignment would work. But as I have stumbled accross this, I try to undertand. **This problem** precisely

Comment: Ok, so your problem is python doesn't pass objects by reference.

Comment: Yep... as the answers of delnan and rahul explains in details.

Comment: take a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/291978/short-description-of-python-scoping-rules, the answer is concise and to the particulate

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Python does not have pass by reference. One of the few things it shares with Java, by the way. Some people describe argument passing in Python as call by value (and define the values as references, where reference means not what it means in C++), some people describe it as pass by reference with reasoning I find quite questionable (they re-define it to use to what Python calls "reference", and end up with something which has nothing to do with what has been known as pass by reference for decades), others go for terms which are not as widely used and abused (popular examples are "{pass,call} by {object,sharing}"). See [Call By Object](http://effbot.org/zone/call-by-object.htm) on effbot.org for a rather extensive discussion on the defintions of the various terms, on history, and on the flaws in some of the arguments for the terms pass by reference and pass by value.

The short story, without naming it, goes like this:

- Every variable, object attribute, collection item, etc. *refers* to an object.
- Assignment, argument passing, etc. create another variable, object attribute, collection item, etc. which refers to the same object but has no knowledge which other variables, object attributes, collection items, etc. refer to that object.
- Any variable, object attribute, collection item, etc. can be used to modify an object, and any other variable, object attribute, collection item, etc. can be used to observe that modification.
- No variable, object attribute, collection item, etc. refers to another variable, object attribute, collection items, etc. and thus you can't emulate pass by reference (in the C++ sense) except by treating a mutable object/collection as your "namespace". This is excessively ugly, so don't use it when there's a much easier alternative (such as a return value, or exceptions, or multiple return values via iterable unpacking).

You may consider this like using pointers, but not pointers to pointers (but sometimes pointers to structures containing pointers) in C. And then passing those pointers by value. But don't read too much into this simile. Python's data model is significantly different from C's.

Answer (score 9):

You are making a mistake here because in Python

> ```
> "We call the argument passing technique _call by sharing_,
> because the argument objects are shared between the
> caller and the called routine.  This technique does not
> correspond to most traditional argument passing techniques
> (it is similar to argument passing in LISP).  In particular it
> is not call by value because mutations of arguments per-
> formed by the called routine will be visible to the caller.
> And it is not call by reference because access is not given
> to the variables of the caller, but merely to certain objects."
> ```

in Python, the variables in the formal argument list are bound to the
actual argument objects.  the objects are *shared* between caller
and callee; there are no "fresh locations" or extra "stores" involved.

(which, of course, is why the CLU folks called this mechanism "call-
by-sharing".)

> and btw, Python functions doesn't run in an extended environment, either.  function bodies have very limited access to the surrounding environment.

Answer (score 3):

The [Assignment Statements](http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements) section of the Python docs might be interesting.

The `=` statement in Python acts differently depending on the situation, but in the case you present, it just binds the new object to a new local variable:

```
def factory(foo):
    # This makes a new instance of Foo,
    # and binds it to a local variable `foo`,
    foo = Foo()

# This binds `None` to a top-level variable `aTestFoo`
aTestFoo = None

# Call `factory` with first argument of `None`
factory(aTestFoo)

print aTestFoo.member
```

Although it can potentially be more confusing than helpful, the [`dis`](http://docs.python.org/library/dis.html) module can show you the byte-code representation of a function, which can reveal how Python works internally. Here is the disassembly of `factory:

```
>>> dis.dis(factory)
  4           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (Foo)
              3 CALL_FUNCTION            0
              6 STORE_FAST               0 (foo)
              9 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             12 RETURN_VALUE
```

What that says is, Python loads the global `Foo` class by name (0), and calls it (3, instantiation and calling are very similar), then stores the result in a local variable (6, see [STORE_FAST](http://docs.python.org/library/dis.html#opcode-STORE_FAST)). Then it loads the default return value `None` (9) and returns it (12)

> What is the pythonic way of performing that ? Is it a pattern to avoid ? If it is a current mistake, how is it called ?

Factory functions are rarely necessary in Python. In the occasional case where they are necessary, you would just return the new instance from your factory (instead of trying to assign it to a passed-in variable):

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.member = 10
        pass

def factory():
    return Foo()

aTestFoo = factory()

print aTestFoo.member
```

Answer (score 1):

Your factory method doesn't return anything - and by default it will have a return value of `None`. You assign `aTestFoo` to `None`, but never re-assign it - which is where your actual error is coming from.

Fixing these issues:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.member = 10
        pass

def factory(obj):
    return obj()

aTestFoo = factory(Foo)
print aTestFoo.member
```

This should do what I think you are after, although such patterns are not that typical in Python (ie, factory methods).

Comment: I never said its a bug? But I have removed that - either way, I'm not sure how/what you expected your original code to do since you didn't return anything and simply printed a member of `None`. It would be the same result if had just did `print None.foo`