# How can I achieve this in python

Tags: python

Here's some code:

```
li=[1,2,3]
def change(l):
    l[2]=10
change(li)
print li
[1, 2, 10]
```

But I want this:

```
li=[1,2,3]
def change(l):
    l=[1,2,10]
change(li)
print li
[1,2,3]
```

For some reason,I have to change whole list in method,how can I achieve this?Anything wrong or my mistake?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python and reference passing. Limitation?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12797749/python-and-reference-passing-limitation)

Comment: I also can only guess at what your question is, but it if I understand you correctly, you're wondering why your changes to l inside change() are visible outside. Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/986145/112308

Answer (score 2):

When you want to change the entire list inside a method, you'll probably want to create a copy and *return* it:

```
def change(li):
   new_list = li[:] #copy
   new_list[2] = 10
   return new_list

li = [1,2,3]
new_lst = change(li) #new_lst = [1,2,10]
```

---

If you don't want to return the list, but want to modify in place, you can use slice assignment (*warning: This is not common practice):

```
def change(li):
    li[:] = [1,2,10]

li = [4,5,6]
change(li)
print(li) #[1, 2, 10]
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
li = [1, 2, 3]

def change(l):
    l[:] = [1, 2, 10]

change(li)
print li  # [1, 2, 10]
```

The reason your approach does not work is that in python, variables are simply names that reference objects. When you write `l = [1, 2, 10]` you're re-binding the name `l` to refer to the new list you've just created, the old list is unchanged and still referred to by the global variable `li`.

The above code instead modifies the object pointed to by `l` by using [slice assignment](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/introduction.html#lists).

As mgilson indicates in his answer, you should make it very clear that the function actually modifies the passed argument in-place. If not, an unsuspecting programmer might pass it a list he intends to use as-is later, only to discover that everything in it has been lost. Giving your function a name indicating modification (like you've done) and not returning anything from it are both common indicators of such functions, like for instance [`random.shuffle`](http://docs.python.org/library/random.html#random.shuffle).

To achieve the same effect for a dict, the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict) tells us that this will do:

```
def change_dict(d):
    d.clear()  # Empty dict
    d.update({"a": 3, "b": 9})
```

Comment: Thanks,if I want to change a dict same to this,how can I acieve that?

Comment: @lazyr So dictionaries and other objects get aliased too? WHat about things like custom objects?

Comment: Here's [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12798328/1292652). You answered just a second before me (hover over the timestamps) :/

Comment: @YatharthROCK This is the first time I've heard the term *aliasing* used about python variables, and it's a subject I'm very familiar with. I don't think it is an accepted term. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/986145/566644) answer for a thorough explanation, and [this](http://effbot.org/zone/call-by-object.htm) more technical but semi-official summary of how python argument passing works.

Comment: @YatharthROCK To actually answer your question, *any* python object can get "aliased", as you call it, since all variables are simply names that reference or point to the real objects. But if the object is immutable, like a string, it has no side effects so it goes unnoticed.

Answer (score 0):

## Using aliasing

> **Documentation:** [List Aliasing — How to Think like a Computer Scientist (2<sup>nd</sup> editon)](http://www.openbookproject.net/thinkcs/python/english2e/ch09.html#aliasing)

You can take advantage of Python's list aliasing (which is [common gotcha](http://www.openbookproject.net/thinkcs/python/english2e/ch09.html#aliasing) for beginners).

When you pass `li` to the `change` function, `l` aliases to `li`, i.e., they both point to the same object in memory and changing one changes the other. But when you do `l = [1, 2, 10]`, `l` is pointing to another list and you lose the aliasing magic. To resolve that, you can use the slice operation to replace to full list as so:

```
li = [1, 2, 3]
def change(l):
    l[:] = [1, 2, 10]  # doesn't make a new list
change(li)             # preserves aliasing
print li               # returns [1, 2, 10]
```

## Using globals

> **Documentation:** [The `global` statement — Python Docs](http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-global-statement)

The changes you're making to `l` inside the function are not applied to the `li` list outside. You can use a global to affect the `li` list you're trying to change:

```
li = [1, 2, 3]
def change():
    global li
    li = [1, 2, 10]  # use this
    li[2] = 10       # or this, up to you
change()
print li             # returns [1, 2, 10]
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do the following:

```
def change(l):
    l=[1,2,10]
```

You are actually changing which list `l` points to.  You need to change the list instance passed in to `change`.  You can `append` to it, you can `pop` from it, etc and your changes will be made to the list you passed in.  If you change your `change` function to what I have, your example will work.

```
def change(l):
    l[:] = [1,2,10]
```

Answer (score 0):

In this code the l is work as common object to whole so you can check by the id() that provide the object memory location.
so that's why you got the last output [1,2,10]

```
l = [1, 2, 3]
print id(l)
def change(l):
    l[:] = [1, 2, 10]
    print id(l)
change(l)
print l
print id(l)
```

if you want your desired output than you use the deepcopy that provide the diffident object to function.

```
from  copy  import deepcopy
l = [1, 2, 3]
print id(l)
def change(l):
    l[:] = [1, 2, 10] 
    print id(l)
change(deepcopy(l)) 
print l
print id(l)
```