# Python: Pass by reference modifies the argument

Tags: python, pass-by-reference

I have this piece of code in Python:

```
def sortList(x):
   x.sort()
   print "Values inside the function: ", x
   return

mylist = [100,20,30];
sortList(mylist);
print "Values outside the function: ", mylist
```

The output is:

> ```
> Values inside the function:  [20, 30, 100]
> Values outside the function:  [20, 30, 100]
> ```

Now, instead of writing `x.sort()` if I write `x=[1,2,3]` then the output is:

> ```
> Values inside the function:  [1, 2, 3]
> Values outside the function:  [100, 20, 20]
> ```

So why does the value of the array "mylist" change from inside the function? And that too only when I perform some operation on it, and not when I assign completely new value to it?

Thanks!

Comment: It's worth looking at this which is related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12797749/python-and-reference-passing-limitation?rq=1

Comment: Because `list.sort` is **in-place**, modifying the object and returning `None`, whereas `x = [1, 2, 3]` assigns the name `x` to a **completely new object**, and doesn't affect `mylist` at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because arguments are passed by assignment, argument names
in the function may share objects with variables in the scope of the call. Hence, in-place changes to mutable arguments in a function can impact the caller.

And in your code at first time because of you use `sort()` function and it change the `x` in-place, it impact the caller and change the x globally!But when you assign a new object to `x` actually you create a local variable inside the function that references to your new object (`[1, 2, 3]`).

So for avoiding Mutable Argument Changes you can pass a **copy** of your variable to function :

```
mylist = [100,20,30];
sortList(mylist[:]);
print "Values outside the function: ", mylist
```

result :

```
Values inside the function:  [20, 30, 100]
Values outside the function:  [100, 20, 30]
```

As another way you can convert your argument to an immutable object that changes on it will raise an error, in this case you can convert your list to tuple:

```
mylist = [100,20,30];
sortList(tuple(mylist));
print "Values outside the function: ", mylist

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/bluebird/Desktop/try.py", line 7, in <module>
    sortList(tuple(mylist));
  File "/home/bluebird/Desktop/try.py", line 2, in sortList
    x.sort()
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'sort'
```

Comment: Could you take a little more care over your writing, please - as it stands, this doesn't make sense. Also, there *is* punctuation other than `!`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe yep..fixed!

Answer (score 1):

You're passing an object value into your function, then you're modifying that object. This changes the object. There's only ever one object, Python does not create an independent copy of the object when you pass it into the function.

Now, if you assign an entirely different object to the *variable* `x`, that doesn't do anything to the object which was previously in `x`. It merely breaks the reference from `x` to that object. Since that object is still referenced by `mylist`, it continues to exist just fine.

Comment: I understand what you said in the first para.. But, shouldn't the same logic be applied to, when you are assigning? I mean, even an "assignment" is kind of "modifying the object" right? Please let me know if I am going wrong somewhere..

Comment: Variables are "placeholders" in an algorithm. They hold values. A variable *is* not the value. `=` puts a value into a variable, it does not modify the value that may have been in it before.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple: python passes argument not by value (meaning a copy), but instead by reference. Thus inside sortList, you manipulate the very same list you pass in. It's up to the discretion of the developer to remedy this. One way would be to use the `sorted` call instead, which gives you a sorted copy of a sequence. Others involve the use of `copy.copy` or `copy.deepcopy`